# is there a limit of merge tables with Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database with mysql 5.0 for an open source project
it's used to stored sentences in specific languages and their translations in other languages

I used to have a big table "sentences" and "sentences_translations" (use to join sentences to sentences) table but has we have now near one million entries, this begin to be a bit slow, moreover, most of request are made using a "where lang ="

so I've decided to create a table by language 
sentences_LANGUAGECODE

and sentences_translation_LANGSOURCE_LANGTARGET

and to create merge table like this
sentences_ENG_OTHERS  which merge sentences_ENG_ARA sentences_ENG_DEU etc... 
   when we want to have the translations in all languages of an english sentence
sentences_OTHERS_ENG
   when we want to have only the english translations of some sentences

I've created a script to create all these tables (they're around 31 languages so more than 60 merge table), I've tested, that works really great a request which use to take 160ms now take only 30 :)
but I discover that all my merge table after the 15th use to have "NULL" as type of storage engine 
instead of MRG_MYISAM, and if delete one, then I can create an others, using FLUSH table between each creation also allow me to create more merge tables

so is this a limitation from mysql ? can we override it ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(thanks to Martin to show me the way)

on linux, you have to edit your `/etc/security/limits.conf` and a line like this

```
* hard nofile 4096
```

At the next restart it will be ok 
To have it directly stop your server

```
ulimit -n 4096 (or more , as root)
```

and restart your server directly

I don't know how about windows yet

Answer (score 1):

In this thread from the MySQL Merge storage engine forum, it appears that many thousands of tables can be incorporated into a MERGE table.  Some people have had problems of running out of file handles, but again this is usually only encountered after a few hundred tables are merged in.  I suppose it depends on what OS you are using too - perhaps Windows has lower thresholds.

[MySQL Forum for MERGE storage engine](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?93,21008,21008#msg-21008)

Personally, I would avoid the Merge engine if at all possible.  I started using it back in 2002, and have been bitten by numerous bugs across many versions of MySQL.  I get the impression that the Merge engine is not a priority for MySQL, and perhaps not very well tested.  Partitioning in 5.1 seems more featureful, but for your application I am surprised that you are having performance issues for only a million rows. How effective is your indexing ?

Comment: I will read carefully
I'm running mysql 5.0 on Debian, as it's the one provided by my host, I've perfomance issue as I do the following 

I need the translations AND translations of translations which are not already a translations,  so the request is a bit big, doing just direct translation is really fast.

moreover the server is not really powerfull (open source project :p) 

I will read carefully your link

Comment: How about publishing the "explain" of your query ?  It might just want a bit of tuning.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xbVVPTsW (for the request) 
the explain give the following 
http://pastebin.com/w4Pypwdq (both are too long to be paste directly here)
thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can improve on that.  What you have looks pretty good in the explain.  Every join is supported by an index.  All I could suggest is doing all the complicated work on sentences_translations and then separately joining the result on sentences to get the text to reduce record reads to the minimum, but even then I doubt there would be much improvement.